# Can you write a 301 redirect to an anchor point?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, http-headers

Is this valid and correct?

```
RewriteRule ^myOldPage.html$ /index.php#info [R]
```

I'm specifically interested about the `#info` part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. That's a  valid 301 redirect (the [HTTP standard](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) allows for any valid URI to be provided as the redirect).

Now the caveat: Not all search engines may love the redirect. Google does a fantastic job of handling anchor tags (they even have a [patent on this](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=/netahtml/PTO/search-adv.htm&r=1&p=1&f=G&l=50&d=PTXT&S1=7,308,643.PN.&OS=pn/7,308,643&RS=PN/7,308,643)), while others will completely ignore them. As long as that's not an issue, the redirect is technically valid.

**Update:** If you're having trouble with mod_rewrite, try the NE (no escape) flag to prevent the # symbol from getting encoded:

```
RewriteRule ^myOldPage.html$ /index.php#info [R,NE]
```

Comment: thanks! I was just coming back here to say about how it didn't work because of the # getting encoded...

Comment: What if we have to point to multiple anchors on the same page? For example: #info, #transformation, #coding-environment...

Answer (score 0):

Although it looks correct, I have a strange feeling this won't work.

The browser needs to know about the #anchor. The server and mod_rewrite may well just ignore it.

If it doesn't work I guess you could do something like..

```
RewriteRule ^myOldPage.html$ /index.php?info=true [R]
```

and then in the php output a piece of javascript to do the anchor jump.