# .htaccess redirect - does this work for all anchor links in page?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, anchor

I am porting a lot of content from flat file site to Wordpress and have my .htaccess redirect for each page as follows:

```
redirect 301 /01-chapter1.html  http://www.mydomain.com/section1/chapter-1/
```

Within this content there are a number of anchor links defined as follows:

```
<a name="106">Link 106</a>
```

My question is, will the redirect above also handle these anchor links so that old page anchor:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/01-chapter1.html#106
```

gets redirected to new page anchor:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/section1/chapter-1/#106
```

Hope it does and that I do not have to implement separate redirects for thousands of anchors :(

Many thanks in advance for your advice.

---

ANSWER

Well I implemented the original redirect I posted:

```
redirect 301 /01-chapter1.html  http://www.mydomain.com/section1/chapter-1/
```

Tested this FF/IE/Chrome and for whatever reason the redirect seems to be behaving exactly as I hoped without any additional parameters.

external links to:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/01-chapter1.html#106
```

are redirecting perfectly to the in page anchor links:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/section-1/chapter-1/#106
```

Thanks for the good advice anyway but so far so good!

Comment: Good you found out yourself, but next time do this simple test first before wasting other people's time. Nonetheless, welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, it does not do that. Check out this blog post:
http://www.mikeduncan.com/named-anchors-are-not-sent/

You can try to redirect client-side with JavaScript instead.

*edit:* More information:

The [301 Redirect Cheatsheet](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/list-of-methods-to-redirect-users-to-different-page.html) shows many redirection options. When combined with the information gleaned from [Can you write a 301 redirect to an anchor point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386709/can-you-write-a-301-redirect-to-an-anchor-point), means that we can write something like:

```
RewriteRule ^01-chapter1.html(#.+)?$ /section1/chapter-1/$1 [R=301,NE]
```

Not really sure of the regex syntax though, might need something else.

Comment: aw crap - I have over 4000 named anchor links used by all sorts of external sites to reach my content. Any pointer on this js option you mention (not my bag)?

Comment: Check out the [redirection cheatsheet](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/list-of-methods-to-redirect-users-to-different-page.html). I think you might be able to do this with just mod_rewrite, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386709/can-you-write-a-301-redirect-to-an-anchor-point

Comment: @user9373 I've edited the answer to show the new information.

Comment: Thanks for the links but don't think they're going to help with incoming links - seem to deal with page redirects rather than making sure someone heading for 01-chapter1.html#106 gets to chapter-1/#106

Comment: @user9373 Please look at the edit I made to the answer, I think this rewrite rule will redirect users to the new page while keeping the anchor intact.

Comment: np, my pleasure. If it works, don't forget to accept the answer! =)